# Complex insert statement using select and joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-insert

I want to insert value into CAPTURED_DATA_01 table. The value for columns in CAPTURED_DATA_01 table comes from select statements and join.So its little bit complex insert statement.The SUBSCRIPTION_ID should be added from this select query which is running query:

```
    Select * from(
select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID  
   from WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL WF,CAPTURED_DATA_01 CP
where WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID > CP.SUBSCRIPTION_ID and 
WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID IN
( 
select iw.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
from (
   SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>\d+</ax2130:id>'), 
   '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>', ''), '</ax2130:id>', '')) 
   AS SUBSCRIPTION_ID , 
   CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(REQUEST_XML, '<ns7:orderType>.+</ns7:orderType>'),
    '<ns7:orderType>', ''), '</ns7:orderType>', '')
  AS VARCHAR(100)) AS order_type,
  TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:orderNumber>\d+</ax2147:orderNumber> '), 
   '<ax2147:orderNumber>', ''), '</ax2147:orderNumber> ', '')) 
   AS ORDER_NUMBER,
   CREATE_DATE
   FROM
   SOAP_MONITORING@FONIC_RETAIL 
   where WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' and WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' 
) iw
where iw.order_type='SELF_REGISTRATION'
) 
and WF.NAME='INITIATE_MANDATE' 
and WF.STATUS_ID=0 order by wf.START_DATE desc);
```

Here is the query i tried but getting the error as `cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables,A remote LOB column cannot be referenced,Remove references to LOBs in remote tables.` in my subquery where i have cast the SUBSCRIPTION_ID,Order_Number,Order_type

```
    Insert into CAPTURED_DATA_01(SUBSCRIPTION_ID) VALUES
((select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID 
   from WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL WF,CAPTURED_DATA_01 CP
where WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID > CP.SUBSCRIPTION_ID and 
WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID IN
( 
select iw.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
from (
   SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>\d+</ax2130:id>'), 
   '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>', ''), '</ax2130:id>', '')) 
   AS SUBSCRIPTION_ID , 
  CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(REQUEST_XML, '<ns7:orderType>.+</ns7:orderType>'),
   '<ns7:orderType>', ''), '</ns7:orderType>', '')
  AS VARCHAR(100)) AS order_type,
  TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:orderNumber>\d+</ax2147:orderNumber> '), 
   '<ax2147:orderNumber>', ''), '</ax2147:orderNumber> ', '')) 
   AS ORDER_NUMBER,
  CREATE_DATE
   FROM
  SOAP_MONITORING@FONIC_RETAIL 
   where WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' and WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' 
) iw
where iw.order_type='SELF_REGISTRATION'
)and WF.NAME='INITIATE_MANDATE' 
and WF.STATUS_ID=0))
```

Comment: Could you post the entire error?  The error detail may give a better clue as to why its failing.  Additionally, you may find that creating a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) may help to show what you are gettting vs what you want.

Comment: I am getting the error as cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables,A remote LOB column cannot be referenced,Remove references to LOBs in remote tables. In my subquery where i have cast the SUBSCRIPTION_ID,Order_Number,Order_type

Answer (score 0):

You can't select multiple columns in a subquery expression, and you aren't selecting enough values anyway. You don't need the extra level of subquery you're adding, you need something like:

```
Insert into CAPTURED_DATA_01(EVENT_ID,SUBSCRIPTION_ID,EVENT_TIMESTAMP,
  ENV_ID,BRAND_ID,BP_ID)
Select '10006',SUBSCRIPTION_ID,START_DATE,
  ENV_ID,BRAND_ID,BP_ID -- where are these coming from? should they be literals too?
from(
select WF.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,WF.START_DATE  
   from WF_WORKFLOW@FONIC_RETAIL WF,CAPTURED_DATA_01 CP
...
```

It isn't clear where the `ENV_ID,BRAND_ID,BP_ID` values are coming from though, you might be intending those to be literal values as well; you said they 'should be added using select join' but to what, and how that fits in, isn't obvious.

Comment: I made little bit  edit now again by deleting the other things to make it simple. Now first of all i am tring to insert only the SUBSCRIPTION_ID into the CAPTURED_DATA_01 table but getting the same error. Please check the question. The query i used to get the SUBSCRIPTION_ID is same as yesterday it was.

Comment: @Andrew - why have you removed the queries from the question and answer? They don't make much sense without them. If you posted code you shouldn't have done, can you at least show a simplified/anonymised version of the problem instead, so this will still be useful for someone else int he future?

Comment: i have edited the question alex now. I had pasted the complete query without changing the information which was not secure. For this reason i have deleted the query.